# Visual Studio 2017 - TFS 2017 - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I installed a new TFS 2017 on a fresh Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter server. Than I created a project with a Git repository in it. Now I want to use this inside of my visual studio but as soon as I choose "Connect" on the specific project, I got the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" message. After that, my Team Explorer looks like this: [image]

How can I fix this problem? I already tried to delete the Visual Studio and TFS folders in my local AppData cache directory - nothing changes. I can't find any log files to check the problem, so I hope someone here can help me with that...

**Edit**: It works in Visual Studio 2015. But I want to use it in 2017... any advice?

**Edit 2**: Tested on 2 other systems by myself and two of my frieds tested it too - all the same problem. But if we use the "Clone in Visual Studio" link from the TFS Web view - we got a "Failure when receiving data from the peer" error.

Comment: How did you create your team project? From web or from team explorer? Did the error only occurs for  that specific project?

Answer (score 2):

Works since the last VS2017 update... So it was a problem from the Git integration in the VS2017. Also on any other PC it works now with this update and without any other changes.

Comment: @sebastain this issue does not resolve currently but as you can see in [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30762/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje-5.html) visual studio team resolved this problem and is waiting for next version of visual studio 2017 release.

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down the issue your could create a team project both [from the web](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project#from-the-web) & [from team explorer](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project#from-team-explorer).

Moreover, since it works in VS2015, fail with 2017. Also suggest you to update your VS2017 to latest RTM version and try again due to this error: [Cannot connect to VSTS and TFS from VS 2017 RC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3395/cannot-connect-to-vsts-and-tfs-from-vs-2017-rc.html)

Comment: I'm using the latest version of the VS2017 RTM.

Comment: Creating projects from the team explorer works but the clone of the repository still fails with the same issue.